Unable to connect to VertexAI from Cloud Run, but it works locally
EDIT
In my case, this was happening because of the VPC. I'm not sure how to configure things so that VertexAI is accessible via VPC (like I said below, I added the integration), but for now, I disabled the VPC and the service is able to access the model.

I have a Cloud Run service running a Flask project. This service has VertexAI integration configured and uses a service account with the roles "Vertex AI Viewer" and "Vertex AI User".
Here are the roles this Service Account has:
{
  "role": "roles/aiplatform.viewer",
  "members": [
    "serviceAccount:ai-demo-vertex-accessor@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  ]
}
{
  "role": "roles/aiplatform.user",
  "members": [
    "serviceAccount:ai-demo-vertex-accessor@<project_id>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
  ]
}

Locally, I can run this project using my own account configured in the gcloud CLI.
Here's the code that accesses the model:
# get credentials and create client
credentials, project = default(
    scopes=["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"]
)
client_options = {"api_endpoint": API_ENDPOINT}
client = PredictionServiceClient(
    client_options=client_options, credentials=credentials
)

...

# classify text

instance = schema.predict.instance.TextClassificationPredictionInstance(
    content=CONTENT,
).to_value()
instances = [instance]
parameters_dict = {}
parameters = json_format.ParseDict(parameters_dict, Value())
endpoint = client.endpoint_path(
    project=PROJECT_ID, location=COMPUTE_REGION, endpoint=ENDPOINT_ID
)

response = client.predict(
    endpoint=endpoint, instances=instances, parameters=parameters
)

predictions = MessageToDict(response._pb)
predictions = predictions["predictions"][0]


Here's the Dockerfile I'm using to build and push to the Artifact Registry:
FROM python:3.11-slim
WORKDIR /app
COPY poetry.lock pyproject.toml ./
RUN pip install poetry==1.8.2
RUN poetry install --no-root --no-interaction --no-ansi
COPY ./flask/ai_demo .

ENV ENVIRONMENT production
ENV PORT 8080
ENV HOST 0.0.0.0

EXPOSE $PORT

# Define the command to run the Flask application
CMD ["poetry", "run", "python", "main.py"]

This code works locally, both inside and outside a container, but when I deploy it to Cloud Run, I get this error:
google.api_core.exceptions.ServiceUnavailable: 503 failed to connect to all addresses; last error: UNKNOWN: ipv4:<IP>:443: Failed to connect to remote host: FD Shutdown
The same endpoint returns a 503. I googled it and couldn't find anything helpful. Most people said it's a temporary problem, but I've been trying to deploy this since Friday and keep getting the same problem. Also, like I said before, I can connect to the model and classify text when I run this code locally.
What's happening and how can I make my cloud Run service access VertexAI?

Edit your post and list the IAM roles for the Cloud Run service account. I guess you are missing a Vertex AI role resulting in the permission denied (503) error: https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/access-control

Hi @JohnHanley. I added it to the beginning of the question. Is that what you meant? When I list the full breakdown, the result is really long and there is no option to download it, only to export to BigTable.

@JohnHanley I changed to the default Service Account and the problem still happens. The service is attached to a VPC, could this be the problem?
